# Import error for python libraries

Tags: python, unix

I have installed python libraries on my user account (as I do not have admin privileges). My python script uses these local libraries, but if other users have to run the script then it gives import error. How can I make my script for other users without ImportError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have them add the path to your libraries in their `PYTHONPATH` environment variable like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/your/lib/python
```

See here for more info:  [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Or, you can add the path to your lib in your script before importing it like so:

```
import sys
# If MyLib is in '/some/path/lib':
sys.path.append('/some/path/lib')
import MyLib
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at my local directory  `~/.local/lib/python2.x/site-packages` and then added  `export PYTHONPATH= /home/myhome/.local/lib/python2.x/site-packages` in `.bashrc`.